# Quanteda Version change of reading hyphens

Tags: quanteda

I have set up a block of code for processing a corpus of speeches with quanteda. The versions I used for coding were Quanteda 1.5.2 under R version 3.6.1.

Now I have updated to R 4.0.0 with quanteda_2.0.1  and my code for converting text data to a corpus goes wrong. The corpus function introduces a double space before and after the hyphen, which is a problem for me because I later on split the corpus in paragraphs separated through double spaces. I see that there is a difference between the two hyphens, but in the old quanteda version the hyphens were treated equally and no double space was introduced.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
test1 <- " further steps – especially in"
test2 <- " further steps - especially in"

test1_corp <- corpus(test1)
test2_corp <- corpus(test2)
> test1_corp 
Corpus consisting of 1 document.
text1 :
" further steps  -  especially in"

> test2_corp
Corpus consisting of 1 document.
text1 :
" further steps - especially in"
```

Comment: You could file this as an issue at https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues, or turn this into a SO question by stating exactly what is your desired result.

Comment: I will open an issue on github thanks!